# python raw_input separate lines

Tags: python, lines, raw-input

This piece of code is too long in the editor and requires me to scroll to see it. How can I break the code down into multiple lines?

```
review = raw_input('If the secret number is too high enter h, if the secret  number is too low enter l and if it is correct enter c: ')
```

Comment: \ ..................

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the strings up and put each of them in a line of its own -

```
review = raw_input('If the secret number is too high enter h'
                   ', if the secret  number is too low enter l'
                   'and if it is correct enter c: ')
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> review = raw_input('If the secret number is too high enter h'
...                    ', if the secret  number is too low enter l'
...                    'and if it is correct enter c: ')
If the secret number is too high enter h, if the secret  number is too low enter land if it is correct enter c: h
>>> review
'h'
```

---

To print out on multiple lines, create multiline string, using `"""` or `'''` (three quotes) -

```
s = '''If the secret number is too high enter h
, if the secret  number is too low enter l
and if it is correct enter c: '''

review = raw_input(s)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> s = '''If the secret number is too high enter h
... , if the secret  number is too low enter l
... and if it is correct enter c: '''
>>>
>>> review = raw_input(s)
If the secret number is too high enter h
, if the secret  number is too low enter l
and if it is correct enter c: c
>>> review
'c'
```

I used a separate string just for readability, but you can directly give `raw_input()` a multiline string, without having to store it in any variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assume that doesn't change the fact that when it prints out it's still on one line. Out of curiosity is there a way to print it out on multiple lines?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I hope you're not mad for editing. It's not important for me to score.already I'm older I'm going to die. Best Regards..

Comment: I am not mad, But truly I do believe those kinds of edits should go to comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
review = raw_input("""If the secret number is too high enter h,  
                   if the secret  number is too low enter l 
                   and if it is correct enter c: """)
```

Use triple quotes for multi-line string.