# Python: Too long raw string, multiple lines

Tags: python

I am using python on windows and the path of my project folder is way too long. For example:

```
pathProject = r'C:\Users\Account\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\Final'

os.chdir(pathProject)
```

How can I break this very long strong into multiple lines in the most elegant way? I know how to do it if the string is not a raw string. However, if I try something like this, I get an error:

```
pathProject = r'''C:\Users\Account\OneDrive\
                Documents\Projects\2016\Shared\
                Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\
                Final'''
```

What is the most elegant way to break this raw string into multiple lines?

Comment: Almost duplicate of [python raw_input separate lines - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102409/python-raw-input-separate-lines) ; however this concerns raw string in particular.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to trigger automatic line continuation.  The strings will be automatically concatenated.

```py
pathProject = (
    r"C:\Users\Account\OneDrive"
    r"\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared"
    r"\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\Final"
)
```

Comment: This solution did not work for formatted raw strings. However, I got it to work by adding 'fr' in front of *every* line, not just the first one like in this answer.

Comment: The key difference here is that the backslash is at the beginning of the line, not the end! Using automatic line continuation does not make a difference compared to using a triple quoted string.

Comment: @Joooeey It matters if you're indenting or aligning the strings on each line, as triple-quoted strings will include the leading whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

You almost got it! The issue is that **raw strings cannot end with a backslash**. Hence, this works:

```
pathProject = r'''C:\Users\Account\OneDrive
\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared
\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1
\Final'''
```

Note that if you put spaces into the triple-quoted string to indent it, like in your example, there will be spaces in your string, which you don't want. If you like indents, you can use automatic line continuation with parentheses as suggested in Brendan's answer. Again, make sure that the lines don't end with a backslash.

Comment: The second code snippet you gave is not a new information and already given in the accepted answer. Nevertheless it also belongs to the first snippet which explains very good the unnamed trick of the accepted answer. Good that you added that!

Comment: It's slightly different actually. That's why I included it.

Comment: This format with a single r prefix doesn't work for me. My path contains folders that start with a lowercase F, and they get turned into formfeeds. With implicit line continuation, it seems each chunk is its own literal and needs its own prefix.

Comment: Wow yea, the thing with leaving out the `r` on subsequent lines doesn't seem to work at all. At least not for `\n` either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ending `\` is interpreted as continuation (to eliminate the LF character; Joooeey’s answer was wrong on this) and the spaces at the beginning of other lines are also included. As a single raw string, this would work:

```
pathProject = r'''C:\Users\Account\OneDrive\
\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared\
\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\
\Final'''
```

I think I would prefer Brendan’s way, but you probably want to know how raw strings work (or not) for your case.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 we can use simple `\` to extend any type of string wether f-strings or r-strings.
Here we put `\` after every line which we want to continue.

```
pathProject = r'C:\Users\Account\OneDrive' \
              r'\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared' \
              r'\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\Final'
```

`\` is used to continue any  statement in python. for example:

```
if some_condition_1 and some_condition_2 and some_condition_3 and some_condition_4:
    pass
```

can be written as

```
if some_condition_1 and some_condition_2 \
   and some_condition_3 and some_condition_4:
    pass
```